# What is it called?

Tags: spoken-english

In English what is the terms used to refer to the hair on the sides of the head? Some people have it naturally and some people get a haircut.
Like "the natural curls on the side of the face" or "straight natural sections of hair on the side of the face"?
[image]
[image]
So what's the hair sticking out on the head and somewhere around the ear called?

Comment: I don't think it they have a specific name for it. They're simply called strands of hair. (Source: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/51721095698795175/?lp=true)

Comment: I don't know of a specific name for those either, but if you are going to describe them, the word "wisps" might be useful, especially if they don't have a lot of strands in them, but just a few.

Comment: @LorelC. What do you think about "locks of hair".  You can have a few locks framing your face.

Comment: "Locks of hair" sounds appropriate, and when you say "framing your face," yes that describes it well.

Comment: locks is quite old fashioned for hair, I would use wisps or strands. There is also "the short bits that don't reach"

Comment: This is a UK site, where they call this hairstyle [Fringe Locks](https://www.harpersbazaar.com/uk/beauty/hair/a43525950/fringe-locks-hairstyle/)

Comment: I personally prefer to call it that "dragged through a hedge backwards" look ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hair that is trimmed short in the front and drapes over the forehead is referred to as having 'bangs' (or a 'fringe' in other regions of the world). Any number of "bangs" can be blunt, wispy, **side-swept**, or in other patterns. They are frequently seen as current or stylish.

e.g. Do you now have fringe or have you ever worn fringe?

Comment: Do you now have **a** fringe or have you ever worn **a** fringe?

Comment: @ColinFine I am not referring to a specific fringe. It is more of a general inquiry concerning whether the subject now wears fringe or has had any prior experience with wearing fringe. Hence, article 'a' not required.

Comment: I have never encountered "fringe" as a mass noun, In my English, you can no more "wear fringe" than you can "wear curl" or "wear bang" or "wear plait".  Having said that, I find that the iWeb corpus has a small number of examples like "All towels have fringe on the top and bottom". However, very few of these examples relate to hair, and "wear fringe" gets no hits at all.

Comment: @ColinFine [Link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22worn+fringe%22+hair&newwindow=1&sxsrf=AB5stBgWP4XBwI-0Ge7gpZgMikmjq9KMDQ%3A1688192648867&ei=iMafZOrMNOu74-EP972-sAo&ved=0ahUKEwjqsJfZ7-z_AhXr3TgGHfeeD6YQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22worn+fringe%22+hair&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEiJ3b3JuIGZyaW5nZSIgaGFpcjIFECEYoAEyBRAhGKABMgUQIRigATIKECEYFhgeGA8YHUiNCVCYAViUCHABeAGQAQCYAbMBoAGcBKoBAzAuNLgBA8gBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgYQABgWGB7CAggQABgWGB4YD8ICCBAAGIoFGIYDwgIIECEYFhgeGB3CAgcQIRigARgK4gMEGAAgQYgGAZAGCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) Here are few example of "worn fringe".

Comment: @ColinFine Also, you completely ignored the suggested word "Bangs" and plainly concentrated on the word "Fringe".

Comment: I ignored the word "bangs " because it did not strike me as an error. I had never encountered "fringe" as a mass noun before, and so corrected what I thought was an error. Having investigated, I find that "wear fringe" does have some use.

Answer (score 0):

These are specifically "side bangs", as exemplified by the image in the EBay listing https://www.ebay.com/itm/283203248625.